# How do I go about Improving wireless security at the office (Radius? Certs?)

Tags: security, cisco, certificate, wifi, radius

**EDIT 1:**

Our environment is mixed, majority OSX with a few Windows and Linux boxes. More importantly, Android and Apple cellphones will also need wireless access on a regular basis.

We have a redhat box available to run Freeradius on. All networking equipment is Cisco based (ASA + Catalyst switches + Aironet 1140 APs)

Thanks to feedback from HopelessN00b, I am currently considering Freeradius + PEAP as my solution. I'm prepping a testbed for the authorization server side of things to get a feel for it.

---

Right now we are using wpa2 key + MAC Address filtering on a setup consisting of 2 Cisco Aironet 1140 connected via WDS.

It's working fine but everybody shares the same WPA2 key and both AP configs have to be edited each time someone is added which is slightly time consuming. We only have 2 APs and around 12-15 people in the office and no need to sync with other locations. We are a mixed mac/windows/linux office. What setup would you recommend?

Everything was already configured when I got there and I saw 2 references to a radius server in the running configurations of the APs but the machine referenced does not seem to have those ports open so I suspect those lines are inactive. Am I correct?

Here are copies of the the running configurations:

Accesspoint 1:

```
    service password-encryption
    !
    hostname wap
    !
    logging rate-limit console 9
    enable secret 5 [redacted]
    !
    aaa new-model
    !
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_eap
     server 192.168.90.245 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_mac
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_acct
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_admin
    !
    aaa group server tacacs+ tac_admin
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_pmip
    !
    aaa group server radius dummy
    !
    aaa authentication login default local
    aaa authentication login eap_methods group rad_eap
    aaa authentication login mac_methods group rad_mac
    aaa authentication login wds-server group rad_eap
    aaa authorization exec default local 
    aaa accounting network acct_methods start-stop group rad_acct
    !
    aaa session-id common
    clock timezone -0500 -5
    clock summer-time -0400 recurring
    ip domain name nyc.acme.local
    !
    !
    dot11 association mac-list 700
    dot11 syslog
    !         
    dot11 ssid ACME-NYC
       vlan 1
       authentication open 
       authentication key-management wpa version 2
       guest-mode
       wpa-psk ascii 7 [redacted]
    !
    dot11 aaa csid ietf
    !
    !
    username ckent privilege 15 secret 5 [redacted]
    username e0f847203232 password 7 [redacted]
    username e0f847203232 autocommand exit
    username 58946b90ca20 password 7 [redacted]
    username 58946b90ca20 autocommand exit
    username bwayne privilege 15 secret 5 [redacted]
    username e0f847320cca password 7 [redacted]
    username e0f847320cca autocommand exit
    username 58946bbf4868 password 7 [redacted]
    username 58946bbf4868 autocommand exit
    username pparker privilege 15 secret 5 [redacted]
    !
    !
    bridge irb
    !         
    !
    interface Dot11Radio0
     no ip address
     no ip route-cache
     !
     encryption vlan 1 mode ciphers aes-ccm tkip 
     !
     ssid Acme-NYC
     !
     antenna gain 0
     speed  basic-11.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
     channel 2412
     station-role root
    !
    interface Dot11Radio0.1
     encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
     no ip route-cache
     bridge-group 1
     bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
     bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
     no bridge-group 1 source-learning
     no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
     bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
    !
    interface Dot11Radio1
     no ip address
     no ip route-cache
     !
     encryption vlan 1 mode ciphers aes-ccm tkip 
     !
     ssid ACME-NYC
     !
     antenna gain 0
     dfs band 3 block
     channel dfs
     station-role root
    !
    interface Dot11Radio1.1
     encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
     no ip route-cache
     bridge-group 1
     bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
     bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
     no bridge-group 1 source-learning
     no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
     bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
    !         
    interface GigabitEthernet0
     no ip address
     no ip route-cache
     duplex auto
     speed auto
     no keepalive
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0.1
     encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
     no ip route-cache
     bridge-group 1
     no bridge-group 1 source-learning
     bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
    !
    interface BVI1
     ip address 192.168.90.245 255.255.255.0
     no ip route-cache
    !
    ip default-gateway 192.168.90.254
    ip http server
    no ip http secure-server
    ip http help-path http://www.cisco.com/warp/public/779/smbiz/prodconfig/help/eag
    ip radius source-interface BVI1 
    access-list 111 permit tcp any any neq telnet
    access-list 700 permit [redacted]   0000.0000.0000
    access-list 700 permit [redacted]   0000.0000.0000
    access-list 700 deny   0000.0000.0000   ffff.ffff.ffff

    snmp-server community acme   RO
    radius-server local
      no authentication eapfast
      no authentication mac
      nas 192.168.90.245 key 7 [redacted]
      user ap2 nthash 7 [redacted]
    !
    radius-server attribute 32 include-in-access-req format %h
    radius-server host 192.168.90.201 auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646 key 7 [redacted]
    radius-server host 192.168.90.245 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813 key 7 [redacted]
    radius-server vsa send accounting
    bridge 1 route ip
    !
    !
    wlccp authentication-server infrastructure wds-server
    wlccp wds aaa csid ietf
    wlccp wds priority 200 interface BVI1
    !
    line con 0
     access-class 111 in
    line vty 0 4
     access-class 111 in
    !
    end
```

Access Point 2:

```
    service password-encryption
    !
    hostname wap2
    !
    logging rate-limit console 9
    !
    aaa new-model
    !
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_eap
     server 192.168.90.245 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_mac
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_acct
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_admin
    !
    aaa group server tacacs+ tac_admin
    !
    aaa group server radius rad_pmip
    !
    aaa group server radius dummy
    !
    aaa authentication login default local
    aaa authentication login eap_methods group rad_eap
    aaa authentication login mac_methods group rad_mac
    aaa authorization exec default local 
    aaa accounting network acct_methods start-stop group rad_acct
    !
    aaa session-id common
    clock timezone -0500 -5
    clock summer-time -0400 recurring
    ip domain name nyc.acme.local
    !
    !
    dot11 association mac-list 700
    dot11 syslog
    !
    dot11 ssid Acme-NYC
       vlan 1
       authentication open 
       authentication key-management wpa version 2
       guest-mode
       wpa-psk ascii 7 [redacted]
    !
    dot11 aaa csid ietf
    !
    !
    username ckent privilege 15 secret 5 [redacted]
    username e0f847203232 password 7 [redacted]
    username e0f847203232 autocommand exit
    username 58946b90ca20 password 7 [redacted]
    username 58946b90ca20 autocommand exit
    username bwayne privilege 15 secret 5 [redacted]
    username e0f847320cca password 7 [redacted]
    username e0f847320cca autocommand exit
    username 58946bbf4868 password 7 [redacted]
    username 58946bbf4868 autocommand exit
    username pparker privilege 15 secret 5 [redacted]
    !
    bridge irb
    !
    !
    interface Dot11Radio0
     no ip address
     no ip route-cache
     !
     encryption vlan 1 mode ciphers aes-ccm tkip 
     !
     ssid Acme-NYC
     !
     antenna gain 0
     speed  basic-11.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
     station-role root
    !
    interface Dot11Radio0.1
     encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
     no ip route-cache
     bridge-group 1
     bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
     bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
     no bridge-group 1 source-learning
     no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
     bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
    !
    interface Dot11Radio1
     no ip address
     no ip route-cache
     !
     encryption vlan 1 mode ciphers aes-ccm tkip 
     !
     ssid Acme-NYC
     !
     antenna gain 0
     dfs band 3 block
     channel dfs
     station-role root
    !
    interface Dot11Radio1.1
     encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
     no ip route-cache
     bridge-group 1
     bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
     bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
     no bridge-group 1 source-learning
     no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
     bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
    !         
    interface GigabitEthernet0
     no ip address
     no ip route-cache
     duplex auto
     speed auto
     no keepalive
    !
    interface GigabitEthernet0.1
     encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
     no ip route-cache
     bridge-group 1
     no bridge-group 1 source-learning
     bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
    !
    interface BVI1
     ip address 192.168.90.246 255.255.255.0
     no ip route-cache
    !
    ip default-gateway 192.168.90.254
    ip http server
    ip http authentication aaa
    no ip http secure-server
    ip http help-path http://www.cisco.com/warp/public/779/smbiz/prodconfig/help/eag
    ip radius source-interface BVI1 
    access-list 111 permit tcp any any neq telnet
    access-list 700 permit [redacted]   0000.0000.0000
    access-list 700 permit [redacted]   0000.0000.0000
    access-list 700 deny   0000.0000.0000   ffff.ffff.ffff

    snmp-server community Acme RO
    radius-server attribute 32 include-in-access-req format %h
    radius-server host 192.168.90.201 auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646 key 7 [redacted]
    radius-server vsa send accounting
    bridge 1 route ip
    !
    !
    wlccp ap username ap2 password 7 [redacted]
    wlccp wds aaa csid ietf
    !
    line con 0
     access-class 111 in
    line vty 0 4
     access-class 111 in
    !
    sntp server 192.168.90.254
    sntp broadcast client
    end
```

Comment: Define "security".  What's your threat model?  Attack surface?  Organisational placement on the security/convenience spectrum?

Comment: wpa2 + mac-address filtering was sufficient for two years so you can induce the threat model and attack surface from that. I'm looking for something with unique passwords for everybody to ensure traceability. Once that requirement is satisfied, convenience becomes paramount.

Answer (score 4):

Kinda broad and hard to answer without knowing more about your skill level and environment, but yes, I would definitely recommend certificate based 802.1x authentication over using a shared WPA2 key.

It's more secure (clients can't snoop each others traffic, since each client uses a different key), it's easier to manage, and you don't have to have some poor helpdesk guy punch in the key for new machines or new users anymore.  A shared key is really just the lazy or unskilled admin's quick hack to "get wireless working," and I'm hard pressed to think of what I'd consider a legitimate use case for it in a professional environment.

If you can't set it up, it might be worth having a consultant in for a few hours to set it up for you, but we're not going to be able to say whether that's a good usage of your money, or if the size of your shop and value of the data going over wireless is low enough that a shared WPA2 key is "good enough."

It's not all that difficult (your Windows/Mac/OSX environment might make it a pain to set up, though) even if you haven't done it before, but you'll definitely want to sit down and do some reading on how to best implement and setup a new Certificate Authority as well as a RADIUS server.  Honestly, in an environment with that few people and that many different client OSes, I'm not quite sure what implementation I'd favor.

And FYI, always redact the passwords in your AP configs.  It's trivial to translate a hash to the password.  (I'll fix that now, but remember that for next time...)

Comment: I scrambled the hashes before I posted them but it's the intention that counts so thank you.

Comment: Certificate-based 802.1x was my choice, based on the research and reading i've done, but I have not found any good guides online. Do you know of any?

Comment: No, but the guide you're going to want is going to depend on your environment and particular implementation anyway.  So I'd decide how I want to set this up, make sure it's compatible with all my client types, and then use those parameters to hunt for an appropriate resource.  Once you've got the broad strokes filled in, it'll be easier to help you if you a question or problem.

Comment: Good point, I'm thinking of using freeradius on a linux box, possibly using PEAP certificates. Our environment is OSX/Windows/Linux so all 3 must be supported. What about the lines present in the configs referring to an already existing radius server? Are they indeed inactive? Superceeded with the previous access list rules or what?

Comment: Though I'm not 100% sure (been a while since I actually had to set this upon an AP), it looks to me like they are superseded.  Local login first, then eap, then mac.  Of course, I'm a little confused by the latter line pointing at a different IP, so maybe you should wait for someone else to address that, or hit up the Cisco support forums.

Comment: 192.168.90.245-246 are our WAP IPs. 192.168.90.201 is our linux box IP, but it doesn't seem to have any radius process running nor is it listening on that port. I'm wondering why one of the lines points at the first Cisco WAP as a radius server. if I can use one of the WAPs as my radius server, then I don't need to touch the linux box, which would be a plus.